# Cannot update property from base class in TypeScript with Vue

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a base class like defined below

```
import Vue from "vue";
class ComponentBase extends Vue  {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.left = 100;
        this.top = 100;
        this.isSelected = false;
    }
    public left: number;
    public top: number;
    public isSelected: boolean;

    public select = () => {
        this.isSelected = true;
    }
}
```

And I use a derived class like below

```
<template>
    <div class="selectable" @click="select" v-bind:class="{ selected : isSelected }" v-bind:style="{ left: left + 'mm', top: top + 'mm' }">
        <div class="componentBody">
            Product Content
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

import { ComponentBase } from "./TextControls"
import { Component, Prop } from 'vue-property-decorator';

@Component
export default class Product extends ComponentBase {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.left = 0;
        this.top = 0;
    }
}
```

I have a reference to call select method from base class in derived class's html template as click event. When I click to something it is firing the select method in base class and changes the isSelected property. However I can't see the effect in html.

I have checked whether binding working vie Vue Dev Tools and it is working like a charm. I can not understand why my manually called method cannot update my UI.

Comment: what does your template's code look like?

Comment: i have edited the question included template of derived class component

Comment: well if Vue Dev Tools is saying the state is being updated correctly, i cant help but think this is a CSS issue

Comment: In Vue Dev Tools my property is not updated

Comment: Have you checked the [TypeScript example](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-class-component/blob/master/example/App.vue) in the vue-property-decorator documentation? You shouldn't have to use `constructor` because you can already do it via `public left: number = 100;` and so on

Comment: I have checked and tried same thing without constructor. When I debug the code , i can see that select method is invoking and changing property. I cant understand why it is not changing on derived class.

Comment: Try using `public select () {` instead of `public select = () => {` because `this` won't reference the object instance in arrow functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is :

```
import Vue from "vue";
import { Component, Prop } from 'vue-property-decorator';

@Component
class ComponentBase extends Vue  {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.left = 100;
        this.top = 100;
        this.isSelected = false;
    }
    public left: number;
    public top: number;
    public isSelected: boolean;

    public select = () => {
        this.isSelected = true;
    }
}
```

I have just added @Compnent before class declaration. I think it is about Vue usage with TypeScript